# How does jenkins determine which local repository to use?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have two jobs running in jenkins both have the following setup [image]

the global settings are

[image]

when they run they use the commands

```
Executing Maven:  -B -f /u01/jenkins/jobs/job_1/workspace/pom.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=/u01/jenkins/maven-repositories/0 clean install

Executing Maven:  -B -f /u01/jenkins/jobs/job_2/workspace/pom.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=/u01/jenkins/maven-repositories/1 clean install
```

Why do they use different repositories?

job 2 is dependent on an artifact produced by job 1.

Comment: `Local Maven Repository = Local to the executor`, did you see what happens when you change that option? (hint: the default value is `~/.m2/repository` which means local to the user running jenkins = shared)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Local repositories depend on the settings.xml of maven if you don't specify it seperately. By default it looks like below:

```
<localRepository>${env.HOME}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

Seems you have different settings.xml on your jenkins slaves.

Comment: I had an issue with using home so tried to use the local executer thinking that referred to jenkins. Which was an error.

Comment: @BevynQ Seems you already have got the answer. Good practice, I just haven't tried to use local to the executor.

Answer (score 11):

When local maven repository is set to `Local to the executer` then the `1` in `-Dmaven.repo.local=/u01/jenkins/maven-repositories/1` refers to the executer the job is running in. So if the job is running in executer n then the argument will be `-Dmaven.repo.local=/u01/jenkins/maven-repositories/n`.

Comment: This was seriously frustrating, grep'd everywhere. Thanks! For reference, I found it in the maven-plugin code here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-plugin/blob/5a3d468d42d65abdc041c4ab441bdb1c96bba17d/src/main/java/hudson/maven/local_repo/PerExecutorLocalRepositoryLocator.java#L25

Answer (score 1):

by default I assumpe that the repository used for each job is :

```
**$HOME**/jobs/**JOB_NAME**/workspace
```

your pom.xml should be located there.

Comment: Yes, but what I am really interested in is where the local maven repository is going, not the jenkins job workspace. I need different jobs to be using the same local maven repository.

Comment: therefore it is $HOME/.m2/repository but this is customizable qithin Jenkins administration screen